# Heroku + Gmail + CNAME + 1&1 = woes

Tags: heroku, dns, gmail, cname, mx-record

Heroku recently said they are moving everyone off the legacy dns they had before and wanting everyone to use CNAMEs.  That's great, except that my client also uses Google Apps for their email.  Turns out that with 1&1 you cannot point a domain to a CNAME and give it a custom MX record for email, which is what you need to route to Google...

Anyone else come across this?  Any ideas on how to fix this so that I can use the domain, specify a CNAME and specify a MX?  Is this just a limitation that 1&1 imposes, or is this "the way things work" with CNAME records?

Thanks

Comment: I've heard of this with other DNS providers and is typically a limitation of DNS control panels that get included when you register your domain name. Your best bet would be to move control of the domain to someone like DNSimple, DNSmadeeasy or PointDNS who will all allow what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with "1&1", but there's absolutely no reason why you should be limited to have two records: one `CNAME` pointing `www.example.com` to your Heroku app, and one `MX` pointing `example.com` to your Google mail servers.

If your DNS provider truly doesn't allow this, there's no reason to stay with them.